# Select string only from dataframe by column value

Tags: r, igraph

Goal is to create a variable with the value of the string in column `c` based on the max value of column `a`.

Simple enough, but when I run the follow code what is printed is an index number and column name in addition to `grey`.

```
a <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
b <- c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h")
c <- c("red", "green", "blue", "brown", "purple", "yellow", "orange", "grey")

df <- data.frame(a,b,c)

target <- df[which.max(df$a),]

print(target)

print(target["c"])

actual_target <- target["c"]

print(actual_target)
```

The `igraph` documentation uses `delete.vertices(g, c("grey"))` so target needs to be either a vector or list if there's a difference.

error given is

```
Error in delete.vertices(tube_graph, c(target)) :   
At iterators.c:759 : Cannot create iterator, invalid vertex id, Invalid vertex id
```

Comment: Do you need `as.character(target[["c"]])`

Comment: just tried that , `target[["c"]]` returns `[1] grey
Levels: blue brown green grey orange purple red yellow`

Comment: yes, because it is a `factor` column, you may need `as.character(target[["c"]])`

Comment: and `as.character(target[["c"]])` returns `[1] "grey"`

Comment: thanks though, it's going to be something simple like that for sure

Comment: What do you want as output?  If you need the column name `names(df)[3]`

Comment: actually I got it, see answer below, pretty messy but...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we want to get the same output in a chain, and note the `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`, by default, the `data.frame` argument `stringsAsFactors = TRUE`, so it converts any character column to `factor`.  By making it `FALSE`, we can avoid the last step of conversion to `character`

```
library(tidyverse)
data.frame(a,b,c, stringsAsFactors = FALSE) %>% 
     slice(which.max(a)) %>% 
     pull(c)
#[1] "grey"
```

Answer (score 0):

use `target_vector <- c(as.character(target[["c"]]))`

but there's probably a more elegant way to do this?

Comment: doesn't work without `c()` around the outside to vectorize it i guess.

Comment: If you check the `identical`, it is the same `identical(c(as.character(target[["c"]])), as.character(target[["c"]]))#
[1] TRUE` because `as.character` works on vector.  and by extracing the column with `[[`, it is a vector

Comment: you're totally right, accepted, you might add, `as.character(target[["c"]])` as an initial solution with the tidyverse solution in addition